# Uncaught TypeError: Vue.elementDirective is not a function

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

When I use vue2.0 and Vue.elementDirective, Chrome's console

> Uncaught TypeError: Vue.elementDirective is not a function,

I want know vue2.0 remove elementDirective?

Comment: vue-validator ver.2 doesn't support Vue 2.0 check the [issue](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-validator/issues/218) on github

Answer (score 0):

Vue.elementDirective has been [removed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Vue-elementDirective-removed).

Use components instead.

Answer (score 0):

elementDirective was removed.
Used directive for custom directive in VueJs